# Firebase - Unable to execute call to backend

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am working on a function that handles user registration and in the process, check if the selected username entered by the user is taken or not to inform the user to select a different one. I have the below code to accomplish this scenario:

```
@IBAction func proceedPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

        /**********************Perform Validation************************/
        if(self.emailTxtField.text != "" && self.passwordTxtField.text != "")
        {
            print("Email and Password not empty")
            self.usernameValidation({(result) -> Void in
                if(result == false)
                {
                    print("Result False")
                    self.usernameErrorLabel.text = "Username Taken"
                }else{
                    print("Result True")
                    //Username is available...Proceed
                    self.usernameErrorLabel.text = ""

                    FIRAuth.auth()?.createUserWithEmail(self.emailTxtField.text!, password: self.passwordTxtField.text!) { (user, error) in
                        if(error == nil)
                        {
                            print("Creating User with Email")
                            /*Create the user object as submitted*/
                            self.dbReference.child("users").child(user!.uid).setValue(["username": self.emailTxtField.text!,"name":self.nameTxtField.text!, "email":self.emailTxtField.text!, "mobile":self.mobileTxtField.text!, "homeAddress":"N", "workAddress":"N", "otherAddress":"N", "profilePictureRef":"N","telephone":"0","friendsCount":0, "retailersCount":0])


                        }else{
                            print("Error occured: \(error?.description)")
                        }
                    }//end of createUserWithEmail
                }
            })

        }else{
            print("Error: Email or Password field is empty")
        }

    }
```

and to check the username:

```
func usernameValidation(completion: (result: Bool) -> Void)
    {
        print("Username is: \(self.usernameTxtField.text!)")

        dbReference.child("usernamesTaken").queryOrderedByValue().queryEqualToValue(self.usernameTxtField.text!).observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot!) -> Void in
            print(snapshot.childrenCount)
            if(snapshot.childrenCount == 0)
            {
                print("result is true in username validation")
                //Username Available
                completion(result:true)
            }else{
                print("result is false in username validation")
                //Username Taken
                completion(result:false)
            }
        })
    }
```

The problem with the above is that the full code doesn't seem to execute. When button pressed, I get the following messages in console:
- Email and Password not empty
- Username is: [value entered in usernameTxtField.text
and then nothing more. Although I wrote many print statements to try and see where this is stopping, but this is the furthest the code went in terms of printing the statements.

Is there something wrong here that I am missing out?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since the `completion:` is the only argument in your function `usernameValidation()`, you can do `self.usernameValidation {result in .. }` instead of ` self.usernameValidation({(result) -> Void in` .

Comment: @Dershowitz123 Thanks for the alternative style. Unfortunately, this doesn't address the main issue

Comment: I think the code is fine check that does usernameValidation returns true ever or is returning false always and you don't reach that code.

Comment: username validation doesn't execute and this is the problem. only part of it does and this is what I highlighted in original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some more testing and then discovered the issue through the xcode console. I copied the following from the firebase website to test fetching the data:

```
ref.child("users").child(userID!).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
  // Get user value
  let username = snapshot.value!["username"] as! String
  let user = User.init(username: username)

  // ...
  }) { (error) in
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

The above showed an error that is "Permission Denied". Following that I edited the Rules in the database section in the console and allowed .read and .write and that did it. I thought I would post the details just in case someone else gets stuck.

Comment: The first blue note on our [documentation page on reading data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/retrieve-data) tries to call this out, but it's indeed easy to overlook. Good to hear that you found the problem.